# Enumeration validation with PHP SOAP client resulting in blank request

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm having a problem making a SOAP call with a parameter that includes a restricted enumeration. Here's the relevant part of my WSDL (the method, input type, and enumeration):

```
<s:element name="createMagnetMailMessage">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="message" type="tns:MessageDetails" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <s:complexType name="MessageDetails">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="characterSet" type="tns:CharacterSet" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

  <s:simpleType name="CharacterSet">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="Western" />
      <s:enumeration value="International" />
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
</s:element>
```

Here's the code I'm using to call the SOAP method:

```
$options = array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true, 'connection_timeout' => 60);
$client = new SoapClient('https://example.com/mmapi.asmx?wsdl', $options);

// ... stuff to add authentication header ...

$data = array();
$data['characterSet'] = 'International';

try {
    $request = $client->createMagnetMailMessage($data);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo 'ERROR: '.$ex->getMessage();
}

var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

Finally, here's the actual request being sent (note the empty body):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.magnetmail.net/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:mmAuthHeader>
      <ns1:sessionId>ABC123</ns1:sessionId>
      <ns1:user_id>USER</ns1:user_id>
    </ns1:mmAuthHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:createMagnetMailMessage/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Apparently when the data sent to a method doesn't fit into the constraints of the WSDL, PHP's SOAP client just sends nothing? Even so, the data I am sending appears valid to me. What am I missing?

Comment: make sure you have your wsdl caching disabled, just to make sure your client fetches the real wsdl document (not cached one).